# Xarray apply function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

I have a large dataset and I want to do some computing on some groups of values.

That works fine, but I am left with the following information:

```
        Array        Chunk
Bytes   17.81 kiB    480 B
Shape   (38, 1, 60)  (1, 1, 60)
Count   57288 Tasks  38 Chunks
Type    float64      numpy.ndarray
```

So I am guessing that when I for exmaple add some variables togehter, it does not perform the operation but it only saves that there is an operation that has to be done, at least that is how I interpret the "tasks".

When asking for the `.value` it takes a long time (multiple minutes). I would like to know how one can tell to perform the tasks in parallel? When checking the task manager the CPU and memory usage are extremely low during the operations. I would like to use all cores and more memory for faster computing time.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am guessing that when I for exmaple add some variables togehter, it does not perform the operation but it only saves that there is an operation that has to be done, at least that is how I interpret the "tasks".

Correct: this is known as "lazy" operation, and this is how xarray uses dask for parallelism and out-of-core compute.

Assuming you opened your datasets with something like `chunks={}`, your operations *are* being performed in parallel when you fetch the values. Seeing "chunks" in your text representation suggests this is the case. That your CPU usage is low, likely means that most of your tome is being spend waiting on IO and other latencies.

A few suggestions:

- you can choose bigger values for your dask partition size than the default given by `chunks={}`, which can mean extra concurrency over IO in addition to the parallelism you already have
- if you create a dask distributed cluster, even the default one with `dask.distributed.Client()`, you will generally get smarter parallelism, and certainly more information about what is happening via the dashboard. This also lets you tune the mix of threads versus processes, to try to find the best for your workflow.
- there are many tasks in your final output object; perhaps some sets of operations can be bundled together into `map` operations (although dak does a decent job combining these for you automatically)